# Is there any faster alternative to POSIXct in R?

Tags: r, posixct

I am reading a CSV with `fread` (as it is quicker than `read_csv` method), timestamp column is taken as `character` type.

I want to convert it to `POSIXct` with:
`as.POSIXct(strptime(rawTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))`

But this `POSIXct` call is very slow.

[image]

Is there any quicker alternatetive to this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can use `fastPOSIXct` from `fasttime`

```
library(fasttime)
str1 <- rep("2015-01-01", 1e6)
system.time(fastPOSIXct(str1))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.08    0.00    0.08 

system.time(as.POSIXct(str1))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  24.80    0.26   25.33
```

Comment: @DevharshTrivedi  It is just for benchmarking I just replicated the same character element 1e6 times.  You could also take a sample and do it.  If your character.  According to `?fastPOSIXct` documentation `The order of interpretation is fixed: year, month, day, hour, minute, second. Note that only true (positive) POSIX dates (since 1970-01-01 00:00:00) are supported`

Comment: Thanks! @akrun I saw around ~40x performance boost. Simply awesome! :D :D